# C# ticket system

Tags: c#, oledb

I am currently designing a ticket system for my place of work.

Currently, I have most of it working except one small part. It is setup to automatically send it to the person that is responsible for fixing it. After it tells the user their Unique ID and the estimated date it should be finished. The only problem is People work different shifts. The things I want it to be able to do is

- If a ticket is put in before the persons shift, it adjusts to the time they come in for their shift.
- If a ticket is put in after a persons shift, adjusts it to the next day and the start of the persons shift.
- If the ticket takes longer than the time remaining in the shift, use the time remaining in the shift and the remaining in the following day.
- Be able to add time from previous tickets that are not completed and maintain the work schedule. (Currently working except maintaining work schedule)

For example:

- First shift comes in at 7:00 am and someone puts in a ticket at 3:00 am, it should go to 7:00 am and than adjust the amount of time needed.
- First shift leaves at 3:30pm and someone puts in a ticket at 3:00 pm that takes roughly an hour to complete, it should finish the 30 minutes in the day and go 30 minutes into the following day.

The code I currently have to try to handle this

```
if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(sum).Hour <= 8)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Too early");
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var tomorrow8am = now.AddDays(0).Date.AddHours(8);
    double totalHours = (tomorrow8am - now).TotalHours;
    MessageBox.Show("totalHours=" + totalHours);
    var today8am = now.Date.AddHours(8).Hour;
    EstimatedCompleteDate = DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(0).Day + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year + " " + DateTime.Now.AddHours(totalHours).AddMinutes(timetoadd).ToLongTimeString();
    MessageBox.Show(now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + tomorrow8am.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + totalHours.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(now.AddHours(totalHours).AddMinutes(timetoadd).Hour.ToString());
    if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(totalHours).AddMinutes(timetoadd).Hour > 15)
    {
        double hourstoadd = 0;// = timetoadd / 60;
        do
        {
            hourstoadd++;
            timetoadd = timetoadd - 60;
        }
        while (timetoadd > 60);
        var remaining = hourstoadd;
        int i = 0;
        MessageBox.Show(remaining.ToString());
        do
        {
            if (remaining > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Remaining1: " + remaining.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Remaining - totalHours" + (remaining - totalHours).ToString());
                i++;
                EstimatedCompleteDate = DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(i).Day + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year + " " + DateTime.Now.AddHours(totalHours + remaining).AddMinutes(timetoadd + now.Minute).ToLongTimeString();
                remaining = remaining - 8;
            }
        }
        while (remaining > 0);
```

please excuse the messagebox's I am using to give some feedback to me.

Comment: "The code I currently have to try to handle this" - okay, great. You've shown us the code, and you've explained what you're trying to do. What you haven't told us is *what is the problem with this existing code*?

Comment: Why are you trying to add time in this case?  It is easier to get current from Now the Day, Month, Year and then create a new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds).  Day will be current day + 1.  Hour the starting time of worker.  Minutes and Seconds will be zero.

Comment: The problem is if after it adds the sum(Which is all the minutes from the previous tickets) occasionally it won't add the correct amount of days. Occasionally it just completely freezes with no error message after it tells the user the total amount of minutes. I am adding time from the amount of time the individual ticket will take plus the time from all the other currently open tickets. Also want it to avoid Saturday and Sundays.